# Difference between Azure App Service logs and Diagnostic settings

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I can't find information about the differences in Azure between:
App Service logs / Diagnostic settings

If someone can explain me in simple words I would appreciate it very much. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for the logs directly in App service logs.

Diagnostic settings are used to configure streaming export of platform logs and metrics for a resource to the destination of your choice. You can export the logs to other resource such as "Log Analytics workspace", "storage account", "event hub" and Send to partner solution. Then you can do other operation with the logs.